# Problema en un buscador cuando se envía parámetros a en esa misma vista en ASP Net Mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Como mi controlador requiere el parámetro **idEncuesta**, al momento de realizar la búsqueda quita el parámetro **idEncuesta** de la url y es reemplazado por el parámetro **searchString** y obtengo un error por que le hace falta el parámetro **idEncuesta**

Asi es como recibe la url: **Preguntas/Index/60SearchString=Nombre**

Como espero Recibirlo: **Preguntas/Index/60?idEncuesta=60&SearchString=Nombre**

Este es mi controlador del Index

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, int idEncuesta, int? page, string searchString)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        ViewBag.idEncuesta = idEncuesta;

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.idEncuesta = idEncuesta;
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        ViewBag.idEncuesta = idEncuesta;
        var preguntas = from s in db.Tb_Pregunta
                        where s.Encu_Id.Equals(idEncuesta)
                        select s;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            preguntas = preguntas.Where(s => s.Preg_Titulo.Contains(searchString) && s.Encu_Id.Equals(idEncuesta)
                                   || s.Preg_Titulo.Contains(searchString) && s.Encu_Id.Equals(idEncuesta));
            ViewBag.idEncuesta = idEncuesta;
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                preguntas = preguntas.OrderByDescending(s => s.Preg_Id);
                break;
            default:  // Name ascending 
                preguntas = preguntas.OrderBy(s => s.Preg_Id);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(preguntas.ToPagedList( pageNumber, pageSize));   
    }
```

En mi buscador tengo el siguiente código

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="buscarDato" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-success tamañoBoton" />
</form>
```

He Tratado de solucionarlo enviando el parámetro por medio del parámetro **name** del input de búsqueda de la siguiente manera pero no me resultado efectivo ya que solo agrega un **+** en la url

```
<input type="text" id="buscarDato" name="idEncuesta SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diferencia de la clase de tu input (class), el name no puede ser compuesto. Intenta mejor creando dos elementos input. Adicionalmente, también ponle el nombre de la variable en la propiedad id:

```
<input type="text" id="idEncuesta" name="idEncuesta" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
<input type="text" id="SearchString" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

El formulario debe quedar:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="sortOrder" name="sortOrder" value="@ViewBag.CurrentSort" />
    <input type="number" id="idEncuesta" name="idEncuesta" value="@ViewBag.IdEncuesta" />
    <input type="number" id="page" name="page" value="@ViewBag.Page" />
    <input type="text" id="searchString" name="searchString" value="@ViewBag.SearchString" />
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-success tamañoBoton" />
</form>
```

Si por ejemplo no quieres que se muestren los inputs por que los traes de otra página puedes hacerlos input type="hidden"

Y en tu controlador yo recomendaría

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, int idEncuesta, int? page, string searchString)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.IdEncuesta = idEncuesta;
        ViewBag.Page = page;
        ViewBag.SearchString = searchString;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }

        var preguntas = from s in db.Tb_Pregunta
                        where s.Encu_Id.Equals(idEncuesta)
                        select s;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            preguntas = preguntas.Where(s => s.Preg_Titulo.Contains(searchString) && s.Encu_Id.Equals(idEncuesta)
                                   || s.Preg_Titulo.Contains(searchString) && s.Encu_Id.Equals(idEncuesta));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                preguntas = preguntas.OrderByDescending(s => s.Preg_Id);
                break;
            default:  // Name ascending 
                preguntas = preguntas.OrderBy(s => s.Preg_Id);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 20;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(preguntas.ToPagedList( pageNumber, pageSize));   
    }
```